# Maintaining Private API for a Public iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, static-libraries

I have an iOS framework that my team uses internally for one of our apps. This framework will eventually be released as a public SDK for our platform.

What I need to do though is figure out the best way to include Private API in this framework used by our app that is NOT available in the public SDK.

The options I have thought of would be to maintain a separate branch or forked git repo with a version of the SDK that includes private API, but neither of these approaches are very clean/scaleable.

I also thought about creating a separate framework that includes the private API and requires the base framework, but with this approach you run into private/public visibility problems.

Does anyone have any advice on what the best practice would be in this case?